# What is the reason for rmdir(1) and rm(1) to co-exist?

Tags: linux, unix, bsd

I use BSD and Linux every day, I have never had a circumstance which I must use rmdir(1) rather than rm(1). What's the purpose of rmdir's existence?

Comment: OT, but, FWIW, this shows interesting (and different) usage: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-remove-directory/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The main reason is probably historical.  Back in the old, old days, there were no `rmdir(2)` and `mkdir(2)` system calls (we're discussing 7th Edition UNIX™ here), and `rmdir(1)` was (of necessity) a SUID root program that used the `unlink(2)` system call to remove directories.

The 7th Edition UNIX manuals are available online at http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan (last checked 2017-04-23); They are also available at http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan (last checked 2017-04-23).  There also seems to be at least one alternative source online — http://wolfram.schneider.org/bsd/7thEdManVol2/ — for the articles in Volume 2, with a link to the [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?manpath=v7) site for the commands and system calls in Volume 1.

The `rm` command (a regular non-SUID program) invoked the `rmdir(1)` command to remove empty directories.   It could not do so itself; that required root privileges.  So, the `rmdir(1)` command (see [here](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/rmdir.c) for its source code in Unix V7) existed to remove empty directories, and the `rm` command did not remove empty directories itself.

To use `rm` to remove directories, you have to give the `-r` option.

There's also a symmetry argument.  You need a command `mkdir(1)` to create directories; it seems reasonable to have a command `rmdir(1)` to undo what `mkdir(1)` did.  Plus they are (these days) simple exercisors of the the `rmdir(2)` and `mkdir(2)` system calls — yes, back in 7th Edition UNIX, `mkdir(1)` was also a SUID root program, using the `mknod(2)` call to create a directory node and the `link(2)` call to create the `.` and `..` entries in the directory.

Comment: aha! this all makes sense, great!

Comment: Nice.  I just checked a copy of 3BSD I have here and there's no documentation for an rmdir syscall there either, and rmdir(1) is still implemented using unlink.

Comment: One major downside of the mknod + link and unlink system was that creating a directory was not an atomic operation, so you could end up with a partially complete directory.  There were lots of programs devised to check file systems for the inconsistencies that arose; `fsck(1)` is the one that survived.

Comment: @Jonathan, bringing back memories of Xenix on that one. Yuck! Yes, really bad things could happen.

Answer (score 6):

"rm" does not work on directories.  You have to either use rmdir or specify the -r switch for a recursive deletion.  The reason is historical: `unlink` and `rmdir` are separate system calls and have been from the early days of Unix.

Comment: A happy side-effect is that you're slightly less likely to accidentally delete a directory when you intend to remove only a file.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that "rm -r" and "rmdir" have the same amount of key strokes. Does rmdir exist purely for historical reason (.. being compatible with decades old Unix programs)?

Comment: Actually, back in the early days of Unix, neither `rmdir(2)` nor `mkdir(2)` existed as a system call; user `root` could use the `mknod(2)` call to create a directory node and the `link(2)` call to create the `.` and `..` entries in the directory; and `root` could use the `unlink(2)` call to remove the directory entries.

Answer (score 4):

Also rmdir only removes *empty* directories. If you want to make sure you don't delete any additional files in a directory, `rmdir` is more safe than `rm -r` (except if you aliased rm such that you always need to confirm what you delete, i.e. `alias rm='rm -i'` in ~/.bashrc or whatever you are using).

Answer (score 2):

Also, `rmdir` makes it easy to remove empty directories with globbing (wildcard) expressions.
For example, to remove all empty directories in `/tmp` without touching any files or directories with contents:

```
cd /tmp ; rmdir *
```

Comment: Consider using `rmdir /tmp/*`.  If the `/tmp` directory is really big, this might run out of space for arguments a little quicker due to the extra five characters per name, but it doesn't require the `cd` moving you around the directory hierarchy.  It's also worth considering `rmdir /tmp/* 2>/dev/null` to avoid seeing error messages (there'll typically be a lot, and almost all of them will be irrelevant for that task on hand).